# Where are the Tesseract API docs?

Tags: tesseract

I've looked all over the Google code site but am just not finding anything that explains how to use Tesseract from an API perspective. Anyone know where I can find this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unofficial documentation for the current version 3.02 can be found [here](http://fossies.org/dox/tesseract-ocr-3.02.02/).

Unofficial documentation for version 1.04 can be found [here](http://tesseract-ocr.repairfaq.org/main.html)

Comment: These links are now dead

Answer (score 25):

The latest documentation is now available **[here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/)** and **[here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Documentation)**.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE 2012/05/26

You can download it from here (version 3.01): http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-3.01-doc-html.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Answer (score 0):

Now the tesseract project has moved to github, and it provide the tesseract ocr online docs as pdf: [https://github.com/tesseract-](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs)[ocr](http://www.online-code.net/ocr.html) , you can download to read.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting here for a quick introduction and tutorial:

- https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample

Which includes a link to:

- https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/api/baseapi.h

It may be best to look at the raw source for `baseapi` (linked above) because the code/comments don't seem to cooperate perfectly well with [doxygen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875712/86967) (at least for [that file's docs](http://tesseract-ocr.github.io/a00681.html)).  However, you can presently find a doxygen-generated API reference at:

- [tesseract::TessBaseAPI Class Reference](http://tesseract-ocr.github.io/a00613.html)

Which is probably what you ultimately want to use as a top-level reference.

Comment: A simplified interface to Tesseract is provided by the [OpenCV Scene Text Recognition API](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/df2/group__text__recognize.html).